# Android SDK in Eclipse Copy/Pastle doesn't work on XML file

Tags: android, eclipse

I got a problem with Eclipse when i try to copy and pastle xml lines of code using the shorcuts Ctrl+C Ctrl+X Ctrl+V doesn't work.

But in the Java's code no problem,

Do you know what i've to change in the options to make it works?

Thanks for your help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated the last version of the Android SDK for Eclipse and it solved the issue

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse has given me similar problems like this before. The XML always messes up for some reason. Press `CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `F` to reformat your text and now try to copy and paste.

Lastly, go to `File` -> `Restart Eclipse`.

Comment: Not working, i think it's really a configuration stuff on the xml file... I don't think it's a bug (or i hope not) :)

Comment: Have you tried turning your computer off and on again. That's what I would do before trying to look into configuration issues.

Comment: It's something that i got since a few months so it's really a config issue or a bug.
It's just annoying ;)

Comment: So you can replicate the issue when you restart your computer is what you're saying?

Comment: Only thing I can think of is a new install of Eclipse which may be annoying with all the other things you have to install. On the Android developer website they recommend not editing anything in the XML because it can cause mistakes. Instead use the GUI editor with the `Outline` window as well as the `Properties` window open.

Comment: you don't install Eclipse, you mean the sdk may be?

Comment: Well, I mean if you choose a new "workspace" really. It will have all new .metadata